# Error 'Cannot modify header information' he borrado ya los espacios en blanco

Tags: php

Buen dia,

he borrado espacios entre las etiquetas `?>` y `<?php` pues esto ya me había ocurrido antes, pero esta vez por más que busco no encuentro respuesta, dejo el error y el código completo en el cual quiero rediriguir a `panel_de_control.php`

Obtengo el error :

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /home2/gabriel/contabilidad.dsinsufer.com/PHP/conectar.php:10) in
>   /home2/gabriel/contabilidad.dsinsufer.com/PHP/checklogin.php on line
>   18

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../PHP/conectar.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario`='$username';";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
if (password_verify($password, $row['contrasena']))
{
    //AQUI GUARDO LAS VARIABLES DE LA BD PARA SER USADAS EN PANEL-CONTROL.PHP
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 800000);
    //redirigir automaticamente
    header('Location: panel_de_control.php');
    //echo "Bienvenido(a)! ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
    //echo "<br><br><a href=panel_de_control.php>PANEL DE CONTROL</a>";
}
else
{
  echo "Usuario o contraseña estan incorrectos.";
    echo "<br><a href='../login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
}
 mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Aquí el conectar.php

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*****', '*****','bd_contufer');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "No se pudo conectar, mostrando error de MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Conexion exitosa';
  }
?>
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: muestra `conectar.php` que es donde se genera la salida de texto

Comment: @Fly Tienes razón olvide eso, aqui el codigo

Comment: <?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'gabriel_cons', 'Siste.456*','gabriel_contabilidadinsu');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "No se pudo conectar, mostrando error de MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Conexion exitosa';
  }
?>

Comment: Añade el conectar.php a la pregunta.. en los comentarios no se puede ver bien el código

Comment: Seguramente el error venga de algun espacio o salto de linea al final del archivo `conectar.php` para evitar este tipo de errores se recomienda no utilizar el tag de cierre `?>` en aquellos archivos que solo contengan codigo PHP. Elimina el cierre `?>` del archivo `conectar.php`

Comment: Esta claro!!!  Cuando se conecta muestras un literal `echo 'Conexion exitosa';` eso es más que un espacio en blanco ;) . Quita ese mensaje y de paso, como te indica @Xerif el cierre `?>`

Comment: @Fly Lo mire tan rapido que no me di cuenta de ese echo, pero si esta claro... es eso.